Ask Before Opening URL on Linux
Today I opened Thunderbird to check my email, and without confirmation, it opened Firefox to a donation webpage. That's fine for Thunderbird, but I don't want any program just being able to open URLs without confirmation. This is a security breach.
On Android, I have multiple browsers and no default. Whenever an app wants to open a URL, it asks me which browser I would like to use. I also have the option to not open the URL at all.
How can I get this same kind of functionality on my Linux desktop?
EDIT:
Perhaps there is a small Linux program that I can set as default browser, and it intercepts URLs, and prompts me for a browser to open with?

What desktop do you use? How did even thunderbird open this automatically without you clicking on anything? That sounds like a security bug, not a feature.

@terdon Mozilla has decided this is an appropriate way to solicit financial support. It's at least doubly stupid: it feels very invasive to the user (go figure!) and Thunderbird integrates a full browser, and could have just as well showed that page itself, and just opened the system-configured web browser when one actually clicked on "donate" where suddenly personalized browsers become relevant.

Unlike Android, desktop Linux doesn't have a central "URL opener" that could implement this functionality. (It barely has working file associations, but that aside, it started as a very opposite environment from Android.)
Each toolkit (GTK, Qt, etc) handles file and URL associations independently by reading the MIME config database and then just directly launching the appropriate app – and programs are not even required to do that; they could just as well look at $BROWSER (if it's one of those programs) or even have a "list of browsers to try" hardcoded (if it's a particularly old program that dates back to Netscape era).
So the closest thing you can do is to literally set your http:// URLs – and all other schemes one by one – to be opened by a "prompter" program (which will then have its own configuration about which browser to use). One such program is GNOME's Junction, but it's equally possible to write even just a shell script that calls zenity or something.
In the "standard" system, URL associations are handled as pseudo MIME types such as x-scheme-handler/http, so (unless your desktop environment lets you do this graphically) the manual way of configuring this would be:
flatpak install re.sonny.Junction
xdg-mime default re.sonny.Junction.desktop x-scheme-handler/{http,https}

(If you plan on writing your own, it can be any program that accepts the URL as the command-line argument, and it needs to have a <name>.desktop file in your ~/.local/share/applications; preferably with the pseudo MIME types listed in the .desktop file but that's not mandatory.)

All of this changes a bit with Flatpak (and/or Snap) app sandboxing mechanisms, as they no longer allow a program to arbitrarily run something – a Flatpak-installed app would be required to go through the "Portal" IPC in order to open URLs or run external apps.
So if your mail client is installed via Flatpak or Snap, then there is a central "URL opener" – the XDG portal system – that can implement a confirmation dialog. Each desktop environment supplies its own portal implementations, however, so if you're using e.g. KDE then such a prompt would need to be implemented by xdg-desktop-portal-kde.

Linux very much has standardized protocol handlers through MIME; unixoid systems have had that before Windows did, and long before Android existed. And Android's mechanism isn't any different: go through a list of programs that registered themselves in a local database as handlers for the URL scheme. And nothing forces an android app to not specifically open com.google.chrome instead of asking for the http://… website-opening intent.

#!/bin/bash

echo "$1" > /tmp/yad_browser_url

launch_firefox() { firefox "$(cat /tmp/yad_browser_url)"; }; export -f launch_firefox
launch_chrome() { google-chrome "$(cat /tmp/yad_browser_url)"; }; export -f launch_chrome
launch_opera() { opera "$(cat /tmp/yad_browser_url)"; }; export -f launch_opera
launch_brave() { brave-browser "$(cat /tmp/yad_browser_url)"; }; export -f launch_firefox

yad --window-icon="applications-internet" --geometry=100x160 --borders="15" \
--close-on-unfocus --seperator="" --image="applications-internet" --skip-taskbar --form \
--title "Choose Browser:" \
--field="Firefox!:FBTN" "bash -c 'launch_firefox'" \
--field="Chrome!:FBTN" "bash -c 'launch_chrome'" \
--field="Opera!:FBTN" "bash -c 'launch_opera'" \
--field="Brave!:FBTN" "bash -c 'launch_brave'" \
--button="Cancel!gtk-cancel"

exit 0

Save as: ask_browser.sh
Change mode executable: chmod +x ask_browser.sh
Usage: ./ask_browser.sh
Set that script as the default application:
xdg-settings set default-web-browser '/path/to/ask_browser.sh'


Watch this video clip of the script.
That's exactly what was requested.  The video is XFCE on Fedora 39.
